# MySQL Distinct Active Users for the last month query

Tags: mysql

Alright I have tried alot and this looks just about right for me , but its def not:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT 'uid' ) AS `Records` , DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `epoch_timestamp` ) ) AS `Date`
FROM `log`
GROUP BY DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `epoch_timestamp` ) )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

For w.e reason it returns a 1 next to each date. If I take out the distinct it appears to give a total records for that day count.

Comment: What happens if you take the `LIMIT 0,30` off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your sql is incorrect, try replacing the single quotation marks around 'uid' with `.

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT `uid` ) AS `Records` , DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `epoch_timestamp` ) ) AS `Date`
FROM `log`
GROUP BY DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `epoch_timestamp` ) )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```